# How can I match and substitute this multiline pattern in a bash script?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have a file `jail.local` and it has sections like this

```
[apache]

enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/apache/error.log

[ssh]

enabled = false
port = ssh
```

I want to

- match on the string `[ssh]` and
- perform substitution on string 2 lines below i.e. change

  - `enabled = false` to
  - `enabled = true`

so that the new text reads

```bash
[ssh]

enabled = true
port = ssh
```

I have looked at using `sed` but I couldnt understand the commands needed to work around the fact `sed` is quite "per line" oriented.
How can I do this substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -e '/\[ssh\]/,+2{s/false/true/}' file
```

With POSIX sed:

```
sed -e '/\[ssh\]/n;n;s/false/true/' file
```

Comment: thanks! I was testing on the command line and needed to use `-i` and it works perfectly :)